# Functions as arguments -- What is happening here?

Tags: elixir

I am going through some Elixir koans and I'm a bit stumped on what is happening in these lines of code.

```elixir
  def times_five_and_then(number, fun), do: fun.(number * 5)
  def square(number), do: number * number

  koan "You can pass functions around as arguments. Place an '&' before the name and state the arity" do
    assert times_five_and_then(2, &square/1) == ___
  end
```

For `___`, the correct answer is 100. But I am not sure how or why, can anyone articulate what is happening?

Comment: Do you mean koans in this sense https://github.com/elixirkoans/elixir-koans ?

Answer (score 2):

`&` is the [function capture](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/modules-and-functions.html#function-capturing) operator. `&square/1` means "capture the function called `square` that has arity 1 (arity 1 in simple English: accepts a single argument)".

```elixir
times_five_and_then(2, &square/1)
```

This means "call the `times_five_and_then` function with the number `2` and a capture of the fuction `square` (which has arity 1)".

A function stored in a variable is called an anonymous function (because it doesn't have a name, unlike functions defined with the `def` keyword). A named function can be captured as an anonymous function using the `&` capture operator, which is what happens in your example.

`times_five_and_then/2` calls its parameters `number` and `fun`. The `fun` parameter is a variable that contains an anonymous function. The function could be any function, but in your example it happens to be a capture of the `square/1` function. The syntax for calling an anonymous function is `variable_name.(args)`. That's what's happening with `fun.(number * 5)` in this case. The function stored in `fun` is being called with the argument `number * 5`.

Let's look at the implementation of `times_five_and_then/2`:

```elixir
def times_five_and_then(number, fun), do: fun.(number * 5)
```

This takes the `fun` argument, and calls the function it contains with the `number` argument, multiplied by `5`. A breakdown of what happens:

1. A function called `square/1` is defined that squares its argument.
2. The square function is captured as an anonymous function, and passed to the `times_five_and_then/2` function as the second parameter.
3. The `times_five_and_then/2` function binds the captured function to the `fun` variable.
4. The `times_five_and_then/2` function multiplies its first argument, called `number`, by five.
5. The `times_five_and_then/2` function calls the anonymous function stored in `fun` (which is a capture of the `square/2` function), with the result of the above multiplication.
6. The result of the execution of the function in `fun` is returned.

Or in other words, `2` is multiplied by `5`, then passed to a capture of the `square/2` function, which squares it, to give `100`.

Comment: Wow that was an amazing breakdown. Thank you for taking the time to articulate!